# How many certificates can be associated with AAD Service Principal?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I have created a test Azure AAD Service Principal with five certificates and this seems to work as expected. What is the maximum number of certificates that can be associated with one Service Principal? What happens when the certificate expires? Should this be removed manually or does AAD remove it automatically?

I would appreciate any clarification on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What is the maximum number of certificates that can be associated with
>   one Service Principal?

In official document, it seems that there is no such limit, but you need meet service principal limit. Please refer to this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-application-objects).

> What happens when the certificate expires?

When your certificate expired, you could not use the certificate to login your application.

> Should this be removed manually or does AAD remove it automatically?

No, you need remove it manually.